# Custom launcher not receiving custom broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, launcher

I have a customer that needs a custom launcher to make his devices like a kiosk, just because he needs the device have limited access to limited applications. Everything is ok so far.

One of the most important feature he wants is the possibility to increase/decrease the applications that can be launch in his devices. I wrote the GCM receiver and it's also ok.

My problem is: I want to send a custom broadcast from the GCM service to my main activity (the home activity). I think the code is OK, but the broadcast is never received in main activity. Any ideas?

My manifest:

```
        <activity
          android:name="jv.android.atmlauncher.activity.HomeScreen"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="jv.antroid.atmlauncher.apklistchanged" /> <!-- This is my custom broadcast -->
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

My Service:

```
        @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       ...
       Intent intent = new Intent("jv.antroid.atmlauncher.apklistchanged");
       sendBroadcast(intent);       
    }
```

My home activity:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver listapkReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);

    registerReceiver(listapkReceiver, new IntentFilter("jv.antroid.atmlauncher.apklistchanged"));

    listapkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {      
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ... Do something.
        }
    }; 
}

@Override   
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(listpkReceiver);

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: have You declared Your receiver in the manifest?

Comment: The receiver is my main activity, dynamically registered and unregistered in main.java. The manifest has the intent-filter.